# Defensive copy of Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, defensive-copy

Been trying to find the best way to implement a method that makes a defensive copy of a Calendar object.

eg:

```
public void setDate(Calendar date) {
    // What to do.... 
}
```

I am particularly concerned about interleaving of threads when checking for null input and making the copy or am I missing something very apparent?

Comment: What's the problem with clone? (I'm really interested)

Comment: Good point, Yeah clone is good if the object itself is not extendable, unfortunately Calendar (GregorianCalendar) is, but clone could be used if i am sure the object is a Calendar and no other naughty subclass. In fact i am using the clone method in the getter of the same class because i am sure that my internal Calendar is in fact that.

Comment: I see, you're right. But if the object is of a class you don't want to support you could prohibit its copying, right?

Comment: Fair point, i fear though the method could get a bit bulky for just a setter :) but valid point

Comment: if you're worried about synchronization and interleaving, then add "synchronize" the setDate() method.  Your comment about "checking for null sounds a bit like the double-check-locking issue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) - in which case synchronizing is again the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i was looking into it, however, if i synchronize the mutator, effectively all i am doing is locking the object with the mutator, i would need to synchronize on the received date argument, but being a Calendar object the intrinsic lock would do nothing because the Calendar itself does not have synchronized methods for mutating it's state, they are all non synchronized so even if i had the lock on the date, other threads could still mutate it. My concurrency knowledge is a bit rusty, but i am starting to think there is absolutely no way to safely defensively copy it :(

Comment: Unless you know the thread safety scheme implemented by the code from where you get the Cal reference (and if there they provide a way to piggy back on that scheme), you can't guarantee anything, in my opinion. That's what I have said in my answer I posted earlier.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(Aimed at a slightly different audience now, I guess...)

I would use `clone()` if I absolutely had to use `Calendar` at all (instead of Joda Time). You argue in comments that you're worried about a "naughty subclass" - how would you propose to work around that in *any* scheme? If you don't know anything about the subclasses involved, and don't trust them, then you've got no way of preserving type-specific data. If you don't trust the subclass not to mess things up, you've got bigger problems in general. How do you trust it to give you the right results when performing date/time calculations?

`clone()` is the *expected* way of cloning objects: it's where I'd expect a *sensible* subclass to hook in any type-specific behaviour it needed. You don't need to know which bits of state are relevant - you just let the type deal with that itself.

Benefits over using `Calendar.getInstance()` and setting properties yourself:

- You'll preserve the same calendar type
- You don't need to worry about forgetting properties: that's the responsibility of the type
- You're explicitly saying *what* you want to do, and letting the implementation take care of the *how*, which is always nice. Your code expresses your intention exactly.

EDIT: In terms of the "thread interleaving" which the original question worries about: the value of the `date` parameter *will not change* whatever other threads do. However, if another thread is mutating the contents of the object while you take a defensive copy, that *could* very easily cause problems. If that's a risk, then you've got bigger issues, basically.

Answer (score 18):

Simplest way would be:

```
copy = Calendar.getInstance(original.getTimeZone());
copy.setTime(original.getTime());
```

But I strongly suggest that (whenever possible) you use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to express times and dates in Java. It has immutable classes as well as mutable.

Comment: I think this won't ensure that the calendars will be in the same timezone.

Comment: Yeah, i like where this is going, i was worried about the interleaving between concurrent threads when checking for a null value and then consequently setting the copy to the timestamp of the original, i think this is a problem that i am going to have to live with. Yeah i have heard very good things about JodaTime, i must admit i have no experience with it though :)  Will take a look.

Comment: @zeller You are right about the time zones. I've edited the example.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee it'll be the same type of calendar at all.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I thought I'd put in my two cents.

If you program by contract, an object isn't responsible for another object's mistakes. Calendar implements Cloneable, which means the subclasses do too! If a subclass of Calendar breaks the Cloneable contract, it is the subclass that needs to be corrected, not the class calling clone.

In OO programming, an object should only care about classes & contracts it is involved with. It complicates the design greatly, by factors, when you ask "what if a subclass breaks it?" Whenever an object takes an object as a parameter, there is always the chance the object is a subclass and breaks everything. Do you program defensively when you call getX() that it doesn't throw a ArithmeticException exception for subclasses?

Jon Skeet provided a great answer too, better than mine, but I thought that a potential stumbler onto this question may benefit from hearing a minor bit of 'Design By Contract'. While the approach is near dead, the methodology has helped my designs quiet a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your Calendar object into ThreadLocal.  This will guarantee that each instance of Calendar is used only by one thread.  Something like this:

```
public class ThreadLocalCalendar
{
    private final static ThreadLocal <Calendar> CALENDAR =
        new ThreadLocal <Calendar> ()
        {
            @Override
            protected Calendar initialValue()
            {
                GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

                // Configure calendar here.  Set time zone etc.

                return calendar;
            }
        };

    // Called from multiple threads in parallel
    public void foo ()
    {
        Calendar calendar = CALENDAR.get ();

        calendar.setTime (new Date ());
        // Use calendar here safely, because it belongs to current thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the below ?

```
public synchronized void setDate(Calendar date) {
    // What to do.... 
    Calendar anotherCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    anotherCalendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

The correct usage in code of synchronized depends on your use case.

Comment: Can also work, I prefer the clone answer though, in a perfect world with an immutable type - clone would be the way to go i guess, but your answer is a valid attempt as well

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to guarantee!

Thread Safety: Cannot be ensured unless you know about the safety scheme implemented by the party from where you got the reference. That party could have given you a new reference in which case you can simply use the reference as is. That party could have published their safety scheme with respect to that Calendar reference, in which case you can follow the same scheme (won't be possible sometimes) to check for non-null references, type and then copy defensively by using getInstance(). Without knowing these, it is impossible to ensure thread safety, I think.

Defensive Copying of Calendar: cloning isn't an option if you don't trust the place from where you got the reference from! Calendar does not support any constructor that takes an existing Calender object and creates a new one!

In short, there is no way to solve your issue. JodaTime is the best way forward.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest the use of "synchronized block" here.

Comment: Synchronization won't do anything about taking a defensive copy.