# Creating a temporary copy of a Calendar object in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I need to figure out how to create a temporary `Calendar` object (a copy of a "permanent" calendar that already exists) so that I can manipulate the copy: `tempCal.add(unit, value)`.  I need to keep the original calendar object unchanged, so I really don't want to call `add(unit, value)` on it directly.

Since none of my attempts at creating a copy actually worked, my current ugly hack is to call `permanentCal.add(unit, value)`, display the desired results, then call `permanentCal.add (unit, -value)` — which just seems, uncool.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar` has a `clone` method, you could use that. All data in it is made of primitives, so you will not run into troubles.

Have a look at these answers:

- [Defensive copy of Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224935/defensive-copy-of-calendar)
- [Quickest way to clone a GregorianCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499113/quickest-way-to-clone-a-gregoriancalendar)

Comment: I really can't believe I missed that, and using Eclipse, too -- the damn methods were listed right in front of me...  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use time, day, month, week, year etc. for calculation purposes, you can copy using `timeInMillis` like following:

```
Calendar calendarCopy = Calendar.getInstance()
calendarCopy.setTimeInMillis(calendarOriginal.getTimeInMillis)
doSomethingWith(calendarCopy)
```

This way you can have the time, day, month, week, year etc inside the copy.

Comment: Further use of `Calendar` is ill-advised. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: @BasilBourque You are right, but we are using it for supporting older versions of Android without using external libraries. `ZonedDateTime` is only supported from Android Oreo onwards. Google is still using `Calendar` in their new samples of Android Architecture Components.

Comment: See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58966675/642706) for details on using a back-port of *java.time* functionality for early Android. There is no need to ever use those wretched `Calendar` or `GregorianCalendar` classes again.

Comment: FYI, the back-port includes methods to easily convert back and forth between the legacy and modern classes. So you can continue to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* while doing all your business logic only with the modern classes.

Answer (score 2):

(Not for Android)

Switch to java 8's immutable [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusDays-long-), the successor of Calendar/Date. This API is an immense improvement, may be a bit overwhelming at first.

There a method like `minusDays(long)` will return a *new* date. Which makes for thread-safeness and all. For instance being able to share a value without fear of someone altering it.

Comment: Suggesting the *java.time* classes is correct. But `LocalDateTime` is the wrong particular class. The legacy class `GregorianCalendar` (usually the concrete class behind `Calendar`) was replaced by `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque totally agree, as Calendar is principally used for a Locale dependent display. ZonedDateTime handles day-time-saving and so on.

Answer (score 2):

## `java.time.ZonedDateTime`

The `Calendar` class is terrible, as is its usual concrete class, [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html). These legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

When encountering a `Calendar` object, see if it is indeed a `GregorianCalendar` object. If so, convert using new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

```
if( myCal instanceof GregorianCalendar ) {
    GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCal ;  // Cast to the concrete type.
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
}
```

## Immutable objects

The *java.time* classes wisely use the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern, appropriate to their purpose.

So you do not manipulate individual member fields within an existing object. Instead, you pass a new field value to produce a new object based on the combination of original values and your specific different value. See the `with` methods.

### Adding/subtracting a span of time

In your case, it seems you want to perform addition or subtraction to arrive at a new moment.

Specify a span of time by using:

- `Duration` for a scale of hours-minutes-seconds
- `Period` for a scale of years-months-days.

Example: Add a few days to get a moment later.

```
Period p = Period.ofDays( 3 ) ;  
ZonedDateTime threeDaysLater = zdt.plus( p ) ;
```

For doing this kind of work, you might find handy the `Interval` and `LocalDateRange` classes offered by the *ThreeTen-Extra* library linked below.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

If you want to do this in cool way, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

This very successful third-party open-source date-time framework provided the inspiration for the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework now built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: This does sound very cool, actually.  How much of a big deal is it include Joda in an Android project??

Comment: Just add joda jar to `libs/` directory, Joda contains a lot of date/time helpers. However I didn't notice that you're working on android application. Joda library might be overhead for you in this particular case.

Comment: Not a problem, more of an academic question anyway.

Comment: Google to find some special builds of Joda-Time to address some limitation in Android that makes initial loading slow.